# How to import variable from a root directory

Tags: python, import

i have Telegram Bot project:

```
bot.py 
----- handlers/ 
----- --------- create_ticket.py
```

in file create_ticket.py
i need import a variable "bot" from file bot.py

i try

```
from ..bot import bot
```

and get an error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: That's not a good design.  If `bot.py` is calling the handlers, then `bot.py` should GIVE those objects the information they need.

Comment: Have a look here - https://iq-inc.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import/

Answer (score 0):

I assume your directory tree looks similar to this:

```
.
├── bot.py
└── handlers
    └── create_ticket.py
```

If you are trying to access a variable named `bot` defined in bot.py from create_ticket.py, try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from bot import bot
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'bot' from 'bot'